# Unable to add a new resource using ckanapi 'resource_create'

Tags: ckan

I'm attempting to add new resources to packages following the ckanapi instructions but I'm getting:

ckanapi.errors.CKANAPIError: ['http://xxxx/api/action/resource_create', 400, u'"Bad request - JSON Error: No request body data"']

The ckan instance is 2.3.1

Here's my code.

```
import ckanapi
mysite = ckanapi.RemoteCKAN('http://xxx',
apikey=api_key,
mysite.action.resource_create(
package_id='XX-XXX',
upload=open('/Users/s/stuff/stuff.csv'))
```

Any ideas?

I've also tried using requests
import requests and get a 404

```
requests.post('http://xxx/api/action/resource_create',
              data={"package_id":"xxxxx"},
              headers={"X-CKAN-API-Key": "xxxx"},
              files=[('upload', file('/Users/data.csv'))])
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS was needed instead of HTTP.